# Why is the instrumental case used in the sentence: Чтобы быть здоровым?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, essive

From what I can tell, здоровым is the masculine/neuter instrumental case of здоровый.

What I can't figure out is why the instrumental is used there?

The sentence comes from a transcript found here: http://www.russianforfree.com/video-smeshariki-a977b78.php

Pasted below:

> Ка́рыч:  Не лежи́ на снегу́ - просту́дишься (3).
>
> Бара́ш:  Ну и что? А смысл не просту́живаться (3)? (correct form*: не простужа́ться)
>
> Ка́рыч: Что́бы не боле́ть.
>
> Бара́ш:  А смысл не боле́ть?
>
> Ка́рыч:  Что́бы быть здоро́вым, ёлки-иголки (4).
>
> Бара́ш:  А смысл быть здоро́вым?
>
> Ка́рыч:  Чуда́к (5)! Тебе́ что, не нра́вится быть здоро́вым?
>
> Бара́ш:  При чём здесь «нра́вится» и́ли «не нра́вится». Я не хочу́ быть БЕССМЫ́СЛЕННО здоро́вым.
>
> Ка́рыч:  Ай... Тебе́ ну́жен смысл?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object **здоровым** here answers the question **быть каким?** (to be which?) which defaults to Instrumental case

> быть честным
>   быть сильной
>    быть (по)битым

With the verb **быть** the object defaults to Instrumental also when answering the question **быть кем?** (to be whom?), only in this case the object is not an adjective but a noun

> быть студентом
>   быть другом
>   быть героиней

It needs to be memorized.

Comment: I would extend the answer adding that there are some verbs in Russian that require instrumental object, but not in the sense of an instrument of action. Apart from **быть** (but not implied **есть**) they are **становиться**, **являться**, **казаться**, **притворяться** и т.д.

Comment: I think it's just enough to say that the passive voice with verbs implies the instrumental case usage.